# C# Delegate and Events for Beginners

Tags: c#, events, plugins, reflection

I am a beginner C# programmer just stepping into the advanced world of plugins.

**What I have at the moment:** I have a base architecture for plugins to provide GUIs, Functions, and classes and each instance of GUI, function and class can be accessed by other plugins. (For ex. if the state of one plugin (plugin a) changes because the user has changed then it can change the text in a label in plugin b to the new user name).

**What I am trying to get working:** In one word. Events. If plugin a has an event I want plugin b to be able to subscribe to it. I am using a generic event handler delegate but it doesn't want to subscribe.

**Resources I have seen already:** http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78974-using-reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-at-runtime/ - Extremely useful

[c# Plugin Event Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345154/c-sharp-plugin-event-handling)

[Firing events within a plug-in architecture vs single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533362/firing-events-within-a-plug-in-architecture-vs-single-application)

The issue is that most people are trying to subscribe to an event in a plugin from an application. *I wish to subscribe one plugin to the event of a second plugin*

**My code at the moment:**

Plugin 1 Events:

```
 public class Events
{

    public event tester testingevt;
    public delegate void tester(object o, EventArgs e);

    public void fireIt()
    {
        if (testingevt != null)
        {
            testingevt(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Plugin 2 (subscription):

```
public void onLoad()
    {
        object tempInstance = pf.getInstance("thisisaplugin", "Events");
        Type t = tempInstance.GetType();
        t.GetEvent("testingevt").AddEventHandler(tempInstance, new EventHandler(tester));
    }
```

I have also seen various MSDN articles but none of them try to subscribe one plugin to another.

The code I am using came directly from the dreamincode.net link.

I have tried many different ways by creating delegate types, taking eventinfo variables to store the event and this was the closest I got to gathering it but the error this code throws is:

> Object of type 'System.EventHandler' cannot be converted to type 'Test_Plugin_for_Server.Events+tester'

Please can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `tester` in your subscription code? And why are you creating an `EventHandler` instance when your event type is `tester`? (That's what's actually causing the immediate problem - the different delegate types.) It would also really help if you'd follow normal naming conventions... and your `fireIt` method isn't thread-safe, in that it can throw a `NullReferenceException` if the final handler is removed between the nullity check and the event raising. That may or may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, it seems that you want something like that

```
public class Events {
  // Usually, you don't have to declare delegate:
  // there's a special class for it - EventHandler or EventHandler<T>
  public event EventHandler TestingEvt; // <- let's make it readable

  public void fireIt() {
    if (TestingEvt != null) {
      // Passing null is a bad practice, give EventArgs.Empty instead 
      TestingEvt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
  ...
}

...

private void tester(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Events that fired the event - if you need it
  Events caller = sender as Events;
  ...
}

...

public void onLoad() {
  // Get the instance
  Events tempInstance = pf.getInstance("thisisaplugin", "Events") as Events;
  // Or just create an isntance
  // Events tempInstance = new Events();
  ...

  // Assigning (adding) the event
  tempInstance.TestingEvt += tester; 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was so straight forward. I thought when you create an event you have to declare a delegate too! I didnt know EventHandler can be used to delcare events I thought it was only for declaring delegates! Thanks once again.

Comment: Just for other people to know: I removed the declared delegate in Events class then it worked using AddEventHandler